# Updating a GUI through a runspace

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-5.0, runspace

I'm trying to update a `RichTextBox` through a separate PowerShell RunSpace, but the runspace doesn't seem to know how to handle it whether I include the first two lines of the script or not (`Add-Type` and `EnableVisualStyles()`) or declare `$TextBox1` as a global variable. This only seems to happen to winforms-declared variables.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '700,700'
$Form.text                       = "test"

$TextBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$TextBox1.multiline              = $true
$TextBox1.width                  = 599
$TextBox1.height                 = 500
$TextBox1.ReadOnly               = $true
$TextBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,5)

$Form.controls.AddRange($TextBox1)

# Test scriptblock
$Scriptblock = {
    param([ref]$TextBox1)
    $TextBox1.AppendText("This doesn't work")
}

# Create the runspace
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.ApartmentState = [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA
$Runspace.Open()

# create the PS session and assign the runspace
$PS = [powershell]::Create()
$PS.Runspace = $Runspace

# add the scriptblock and add the argument as reference variables
$PS.AddScript($Scriptblock)
$PS.AddArgument([ref]$TextBox1)

# Invoke the scriptblock
$PS.BeginInvoke()

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A runspace runs in another, isolated, space. Objects/varaiables from other spaces can not be used. I do not have time now to change your code. Read this [link](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/) Your solution is there. Been there, done that

Comment: Thanks/Dankje Gert, I will have a look.

Comment: So I ended up putting the processing in a runspace and outside of it a simple `while` loop with `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` in it, a monitor for the runspace and a short sleep gap. When the runspace task finishes, I add the data to the GUI from variables shared with the runspace (synchronized collection) as explained in the link @GertJanKraaijeveld shared.

This maybe wasn't exactly the way I wanted to handle it, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback